# Show that every sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a monotone subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I would like some hints as to how to proceed on this problem as I am stuck with a particular case. I divided this proof up into 2 cases, where the sequence is convergent and the sequence is divergent.I am somewhat confident that I have shown this for the case where the sequence is convergent, and I am currently stumped on the case for divergent sequences.

My intuition tells me that because the sequence is divergent, I can pick some $p\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the subsequence of points which move farther and farther away from $p$, and that will give me my monotone subsequence. But in negating the definition of convergence I am only guaranteed that there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $n>N$ such that $|x_n-p|\geq \epsilon$, so these point can fluctuate between being exactly within $\epsilon$ of $p$ or more than $\epsilon$, and I don't have enough info about the behavior of the sequence to assure myself of a monotone subsequence.

So how can I proceed from here (assuming that I am on the right track)? Or is there a better route that I can take which does not involve a proof split into cases?

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: I know this theorem, I'm doing a problem in my textbook which leads up to proving it a different way.

Comment: Ok. So when you say divergent what do you mean? That is oscillates (or more generally does not converge) or that it *diverges* to $\pm\infty$?

Comment: In my class was not a lot of emphasis on the kind of divergence, just the fact that it diverged, so I guess this is just divergence in general.

Comment: *So it could be both oscillation and going off to infinity.

Comment: Ok, if it goes of to infinity, can you see that you are done? So, it remains to prove the statement for bounded sequences that do not converge.

Comment: Yes I can see that. And from what I can see after a little research we can categorize divergent sequences into oscillating, alternating, and having an infinite limit?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to divide this into divergent/convergent sequences. Maybe this hint will already do:

For the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ we call $k\in\mathbb N$ a spike of the sequence, if $a_k\geq a_n$ for all $n\geq k$. Now think about what happens if there are infinte many spikes? What if there are only finite many spikes?

Comment: If there are infinitely many then you can create a new monotone decreasing subsequence of spikes, but I'm not too sure about finitely many.

Comment: If we only have finitely many there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that no $n\geq N$ is a spike.

Comment: My intuition tells me that if it has finitely many spikes then after this $N$ for which there is no more spikes afterward it cannot be oscillating, or decreasing (otherwise it would have more spikes), so it must be increasing and therefore monotone oncreasing after this $N$?

Comment: Also, where did you get this perspective of considering "spikes" in the sequence from? This seems like a pretty useful tool to have in your belt and I would like to familiarize myself a little more with this topic.

Comment: @SirJective It's in fact, a special case of [infinite Ramsey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey's_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem), a combinatorial stuff.

Comment: That is basically the idea, yes. Let $n_1>N$. Then there exists $n_2>n_1$ with $a_{n_2}\geq a_{n_1}$ because $n_1$ is not a spike. Now iterate this process.

Answer (score 2):

if any value has infinite support we are done. otherwise there is an infinite subsequence of positive (or negative) terms $r_j (-r_j)$.

if the sequence is unbounded, we are done.

otherwise by the Heine-Borel theorem there is an accumulation point $a$. remove any terms equal to $a$ and after this reduction let $r^+$ and $r^-$ denote the subsequences of terms $\gt a$ and $\lt a$ respectively. at least one must be infinite. suppose this is $r^+$

set $k_1=1$ since $r^+_{k_1} \gt a$ we can find $r^+_{k_2} \in (a,r^+_{k_1})$

the subsequence $r^+_{k_n}$ is monotonic decreasing

Answer (score 1):

Can you consider three cases?

First, when it is not bounded from above. Then consider the subsequence defined as follows: $n_1=1$ and $n_k$ is the smallest number such that 
$$a_{n_k} >  a_{n_1}, \ldots ,a_{n_{k-1}}$$

Second, when it is not bounded from below, similarly,  $n_k$ is the smallest number such that 
$$a_{n_k} < a_{n_1}, \ldots ,a_{n_{k-1}}$$

Third, when it is bounded from above and below, so has a convergent subsequence with limit $a$. Let us consider only the subcase when infinitely many terms of that subsequence are $>a$. Now get a subsequence of that that decreasingly converges to $a$ similarly to the case above.

${\bf Added:}$ It is hard to improve on the lovely solution of @Hirshy:
But since in the comments the [infinite Ramsey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem) let's sketch a proof using this:

Let $I$, $J$ be totally ordered sets, with $I$ infinite and $\phi\colon I \to J$ any map. Then there exists $I_0 \subset I$ infinite so that $\phi_{\mid I_0}$ is either constant, or strictly increasing, or strictly decreasing. Indeed, color the subsets with $2$ elements $\{i,j\}$ of $I$, $i< j$, with R if $\phi(i) < \phi(j)$, B if $\phi(i)= \phi(j)$, and G if $\phi(i) > \phi(j)$. By Ramsey, there exists $I_0 \subset I$ so that all the subsets of $I$ have the same color.

Since we are talking about Ramsey theorem, we also have a finite version of it, that could be applied to the finite case of the problem. However, we have a direct result of Erdos et al stating: from a finite sequence of (distinct) real  $mn+1$ numbers one can extract an increasing subsequence of length $m+1$, or a decreasing subsequence of length $n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=(u_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $[u]\in{}^{\ast}\mathbb{R}$ be the hyperreal number obtained as the equivalence class of the sequence $u$ in the ultrapower construction. We then exploit the order of ${}^{\ast}\mathbb{R}$ to construct a monotone subsequence as follows.

If $[u]$ is infinite, we construct a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ recursively by choosing $u_{n_{k+1}}$ always closer to $[u]$ than the previous term.  The subsequence will be increasing or decreasing depending on the sign of $[u]$.

If $[u]$ is a standard real number, then the subset of indices $n$ for which $[u]=u_n$ is infinite, and enumerating this subset of $\mathbb{N}$ we obtain the desired subsequence.

If $[u]$ is finite but nonstandard, we round it off to its nearest real $r$. Then we recursively choose $u_{n_{k+1}}$ closer to $r$ than the previous term $u_{n_{k}}$.  The subsequence will be increasing or decreasing depending on the sign of the infinitesimal $[u]-r$.

Such an approach is presented in [this 2018 publication in *Open Mathematics*](https://doi.org/10.1515/math-2018-0015); see also [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00312).